# Ugly White background when frame refreshes - HTML - PHP

Tags: php, html, background

I have a small php file named status.php

```
// status.php code    
// has background: #cfdeff by style.css
<?php
<html><title>Status</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2">
$sql1="select * from blah blah"
.
.
echo $row1[0]
```

Then I have another PHP file that has frames.

```
// code of new.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Frames</title>
</head>
<frameset border="0" cols="85%,15%">
<frame name="left" src="blah.php" />
<frame name="right" src="status.php" />"
<noframes>
<body>
Frame not supported.
</body>
</noframes>
</frameset>
</html>
```

The background for new.php, status.php and warning.php is blue-greenish

When I open status.php from the browser things are fine and the page is refreshed as expected every 2 seconds.

However when I open it from new.php (from where I actually want it) the status.php frame also refreshes every 2 seconds as expected, but there is a small blink of white background between the refreshes (the time it takes to load)

So it looks very ugly when the white background flashes between the original background.

So there is anyway to over some this problem ? I searched a lot but couldn't find anything.

I hope I made myself understandable

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe add a the same background color to the frame?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @Mirage : I have tried that

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
frame {
    background: none;
}
```

Or otherwise, make the background of the frame same as the main background like this:

```
frame {
    background: /*properties here*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop these blinking effect.
But you can hide them:

```
<iframe
     width=500px
     height=300px
     id = 'myFrame' 
     style='position:absolute;top:0;'
             src = 'http://jsfiddle.net/' 
    >      
    </iframe>

  <div id = 'myLoad'
       style='float:top;top:0;
              position:absolute;
              background-color:#CCC;
              min-width:500px; 
              min-height:300px;

             '>
    <div style='position:absolute;top:130px;left:200px;'>
        <b>  Loading... </b> 
    </div>               
  </div>
```

jquery code:

```
var ifr = document.getElementById('myFrame');

setFrame();
setInterval(setFrame, 2000);

function setFrame() {
  $('#myLoad').fadeIn(200, setAdress);
}

function setAdress() {
  ifr.onload=function() {  $('#myLoad').fadeOut(200) ;}
  ifr.src = 'http://jsfiddle.net/';  
}
```

**What's the effect?**

Until the frame's loading, a loading message is been shown. If the frame's loaded, you see the frame